# If a function expects a return value, but inside the function i catch an error and want to break out

Tags: c#

If a function expects a return value, but inside the function i catch an error and want to break out of that function, how do I do this in C#... My issue is this **(feel free to skip to the commented lines):**

```
    public static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string props = "")
    {
        string query = url + "?oauth_token=" + Contract.access_token + props;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(APIURL + query);
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(response.ContentType);
            System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string data;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            responseStream.Close();

            APIError error = new APIError ();
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(APIError ));
                    error = (APIError )serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(error.error_description);
                return null; // I WANT TO BREAK OUT HERE, I really don't want the application to continue its thread... Is there a way of doing this without having to go and code all my controller model calls to try and catch?
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return data; // The api did not return an error so continue as normal
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var we = ex.InnerException as WebException;
            if (we != null)
            {
                var resp = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                var code = resp.StatusCode;
                MessageBox.Show("RespCallback Exception raised! Message:{0}" + we.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Status:{0}", we.Status);
                return we.Message;
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: IMO, you are putting your exception handling in the wrong place.  If you want to abort execution then you should let the exception bubble up (or wrap it in a new one) and handle it at the top-level where it actually makes sense to message to the user and/or write to a log.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want the function to do in case of an error (what do you mean by *break out of the function*)? There are only two options: return a value or throw an exception.

Comment: I mean that, if the streamreader does successfully create an APIError object, then throw a message to the user displaying the api's error... then direct him to the login page. (errors will only be thrown if the user has reached his usage limit of the api...)

Comment: Ok. Do you want all this (display an error and redirect to the login page) to be handled in this function?

Comment: Pretty much, GetData is where all API calls are routed, and because I call this GetData from across my application, I don't want to have to try and catch on every call... rather try and catch here... so that if it indeed is an error returned, it cancels any current tasks and just redirects to my login page.

Comment: But what should happen to the caller? How should it behave in case of an error? If you really want to terminate the thread, well, then just do it before you return some value, it should not matter which. But IMHO that's insane. I would rethink the function from the perspective of the caller: what does the function return in case of success and what happens in case of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't catch the exception.

Leave the exception to be caught by the caller - or, optionally catch it and wrap it in your own `Exception` type.

You're putting all of your eggs in one basket here - catching it so far down leaves you little wiggle room. Letting it bubble up gives you more options for handling it.

Comment: I really want to do this, but it means that across my application I'm going to have to change every repository calling bit of code to catch an error... Although I guess I can spend a few hours going through the controllers if there is no other option

Comment: That depends entirely on what you want to do with it though. If you just want to log it.. then wire up the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event and log it. If you need to perform a specific task - perhaps you can still perform that in a global "error happened" event. That could get messy - but its an option (given that I don't actually know your use case).

Comment: I did unfortunately put it in UnhandledException for now.. I may go and try and catch on the callers when I have more time, for now this should be fine. Thanks man

Comment: No problem. Your other option is some sort of Fascade that does the calling and catching of the exception. Then all of your callers call the one Fascade and it handles the exception for them. The idea here is that it removes the need to handle it down in the core of your code and delegates it to something further up.

Answer (score 0):

Put throw() at the end of your catch() statement. Then it will handle it, but throw the same exception again to bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling code should be handling the exceptions. If your execution cannot continue, let the exception bubble up and remove some of the unnecessary try/catch in your method here.